# App rejected with ambiguous crash log

Tags: ios, crash, crash-reports, symbolicatecrash

Apple rejected my app with a crash report,  I have tried symbolicating with the dSYM file from the original app build for the store and this is the crashlogs.

Seems that the app crash on start, but I tried to install the same version sent to them on my devices and it works as expected on my device. Any idea?

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Triggered by Thread:  0
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1832fe59c 0x1831d8000 + 1205660
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x193f640e4 0x193f5c000 + 32996
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1831e91f8 0x1831d8000 + 70136
3   UIKit                           0x187b4c858 0x187aa0000 + 706648
4   UIKit                           0x187b6d9f4 0x187aa0000 + 842228
5   UIKit                           0x187eb307c 0x187aa0000 + 4272252
6   UIKit                           0x187b6eca4 0x187aa0000 + 847012
7   UIKit                           0x187fcd718 0x187aa0000 + 5429016
8   UIKit                           0x187ab0844 0x187aa0000 + 67652
9   UIKit                           0x187ab07b0 0x187aa0000 + 67504
10  UIKit                           0x187fccfbc 0x187aa0000 + 5427132
11  UIKit                           0x187fcace8 0x187aa0000 + 5418216
12  UIKit                           0x187adc788 0x187aa0000 + 247688
13  UIKit                           0x187d47238 0x187aa0000 + 2781752
14  UIKit                           0x187d46cec 0x187aa0000 + 2780396
15  UIKit                           0x187d46c44 0x187aa0000 + 2780228
16  UIKit                           0x187d3a578 0x187aa0000 + 2729336
17  UIKit                           0x187d39fe0 0x187aa0000 + 2727904
18  FrontBoardServices              0x18b549edc 0x18b540000 + 40668
19  FrontBoardServices              0x18b55962c 0x18b540000 + 103980
20  CoreFoundation                  0x1832b6a28 0x1831d8000 + 911912
21  CoreFoundation                  0x1832b5b30 0x1831d8000 + 908080
22  CoreFoundation                  0x1832b4154 0x1831d8000 + 901460
23  CoreFoundation                  0x1831e10a4 0x1831d8000 + 37028
24  UIKit                           0x187b1b3c8 0x187aa0000 + 504776
25  UIKit                           0x187b163c0 0x187aa0000 + 484288
26  My App                          0x100016424 main (main.m:26)
27  libdyld.dylib                   0x1945d2a08 0x1945d0000 + 10760


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001946eb270 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194789224 pthread_kill + 108
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000194662b14 abort + 108
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000193735414 abort_message + 112
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000193754b88 default_terminate_handler() + 300
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000193f643bc _objc_terminate() + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000193751bb0 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 12
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000193751738 __cxa_rethrow + 140
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000193f64290 objc_exception_rethrow + 40
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001831e1150 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 568
10  UIKit                           0x0000000187b1b3c4 -[UIApplication _run] + 548
11  UIKit                           0x0000000187b163bc UIApplicationMain + 1484
12  My App                          0x0000000100016420 main (main.m:26)
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001945d2a04 start + 0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 15/01/2015**
I did the symbolication on the previous crash logs but the backtrace was still hiding same property so I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176393/symbolicatecrash-with-xcode-4-2-not-symbolicating-system-symbols?answertab=active#tab-top) the solution to solve the backtrace. Basically I had a better report attaching another device:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1832fe59c __exceptionPreprocess + 132
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x193f640e4 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1831e91f8 -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 972
3   UIKit                           0x187b4c858 -[UILabel _setLineBreakMode:] + 616
4   UIKit                           0x187b6d9f4 -[UIButtonLabel setLineBreakMode:] + 108
5   UIKit                           0x187eb307c -[UIButton _setupTitleViewRequestingLayout:] + 204
6   UIKit                           0x187b6eca4 -[UIButton titleLabel] + 56
7   UIKit                           0x187fcd718 -[UIZoomViewController loadView] + 568
8   UIKit                           0x187ab0844 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 88
9   UIKit                           0x187ab07b0 -[UIViewController view] + 32
10  UIKit                           0x187fccfbc -[UIZoomViewController init] + 92
11  UIKit                           0x187fcace8 -[UIClassicController _setupWindow] + 584
12  UIKit                           0x187adc788 +[UIClassicController sharedClassicController] + 172
13  UIKit                           0x187d47238 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 724
14  UIKit                           0x187d46cec __88-[UIApplication _handleApplicationLifecycleEventWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 140
15  UIKit                           0x187d46c44 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationLifecycleEventWithScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 380
16  UIKit                           0x187d3a578 -[UIApplication scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 512
17  UIKit                           0x187d39fe0 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 380
18  FrontBoardServices              0x18b549edc __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 248
19  FrontBoardServices              0x18b55962c __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 28
20  CoreFoundation                  0x1832b6a28 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ +20
21  CoreFoundation                  0x1832b5b30 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 312
22  CoreFoundation                  0x1832b4154 __CFRunLoopRun + 1756
23  CoreFoundation                  0x1831e10a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
24  UIKit                           0x187b1b3c8 -[UIApplication _run] + 552
25  UIKit                           0x187b163c0 UIApplicationMain + 1488
26  MyApp                           0x100016424 main (main.m:26)
27  libdyld.dylib                   0x1945d2a08 start + 4


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001946eb270 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194789224 pthread_kill + 108
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000194662b14 abort + 108
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000193735414 abort_message + 112
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000193754b88 default_terminate_handler() + 300
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000193f643bc _objc_terminate() + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000193751bb0 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 12
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000193751738 __cxa_rethrow + 140
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000193f64290 objc_exception_rethrow + 40
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001831e1150 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 568
10  UIKit                           0x0000000187b1b3c4 -[UIApplication _run] + 548
11  UIKit                           0x0000000187b163bc UIApplicationMain + 1484
12  MyApp                           0x0000000100016420 main (main.m:26)
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001945d2a04 start + 0
```

Cheers

Comment: Make sure you install the release version. Ie archive the project in Xcode and get hold of the api file and install it through iTunes. Running the same version from Xcode to your device will install the debug version. Not the same exact thing.

Comment: Did you test your app on different simulators with the same result? Different iOS version 7.1,8+? Let us kow the result from simulators/iOS version and real  device/iOS version. I hope that error appear on simulator or different iOS version. Some libs are supported only on 8.+ ver.

Comment: @Fogmeister I tested the same exact version sent to apple, using iTunes as they suggested in their email.

Comment: How did you test that version? How did you install it to your device?

Comment: @Elensar yes I did but nothing. The app works always on my devices

Comment: @Fogmeister I followed this instruction: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1764/_index.html

Comment: Ah ok. Yeah, not sure then sorry. Can you show the code in your did finish launching method.

Answer (score 1):

Try-

1. Loading the App through iTunes if you haven't already
2. Using something like TestFlight to launch beta tests of your app, and see if it crashes there
3. If you still don't encounter any problems, contact the App Review team through the Resolution Center in iTunesConnect, and sort out the problem with them

Note: I had a similar problem, where Apple rejected my app saying it was crashing when in truth it wasn't. When I contacted The Review Team, turned out that they had tested another app, and mixed up which one to reject! At times, they do make strange mistakes, so its always good to just contact them once. No harm no foul.

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

At finally I found the solution reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27024823/my-app-crash-on-ipad-before-even-applicationdidfinishlaunchingwithoptions?answertab=active#tab-top). The crash was related to the font, but it happened only on the iPad device that I was not testing